# Get the data from java.awt.List

Tags: java, list, awt

In my application i should get the data from `java.awt.List`, and delete the particular value form the list.How can I do it? Please give me the suggestions.

My code

```
import java.awt.List;

List lst=new List(15,false);
for (Entry<String, String> entry : list.entrySet()) {
  String client_Name=entry.getKey();
  lst.add(client_Name + "\n");//here i should get the data and delete particular data
  String listName=lst.getName();
  System.out.println(listName);
}
```

Comment: *"Plz give me the suggestions."*  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: 3) Are you sure did you really search before asking ?

Comment: yes.Really i searched a lot.i couldn't get inside the function.

Comment: Where is `list` defined? Is that just a typo for `lst`?

Comment: You really want to post something that people could copy, paste and run (or that you think *should* run, but doesn't).

Comment: Do you know the usage of entrySet()?

Comment: i know..i get the data from map and stored into java.awt.List.From that i cant get the data.

Comment: Can I double check you are really writing an AWT graphical application? Otherwise, you probably want to use `java.util.List`.

Comment: Have look this Link

http://samplecodez.com/java/list.php

Hope it's help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getItemsCount()` and then use `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` to iterate over the items and remove item using `remove(i)`.

Comment: +1 but notice, I'd suggest to for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) { instead, because DefaultListModel descreasing no. Items internally, just to avoiding index(or whatever) arrays exception